# Flash - Continue Script despite Running Slow Warning

Tags: flash, actionscript

My program requires multiple random recursions, and I have to manually let the script continue past a warning that keeps popping up:

"A script in this movie is causing flash player to run slowly."

Is it possible to automatically continue past this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the script timeout in the Flash Authoring tools publish settings (CTRL+SHIFT+F12), it's the last setting on the Flash tab. If you're using mxmlc to compile, check out the [-default-script-limits parameter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html).

It is however a better idea to split your calculation up over multiple frames, users will very likely think your app is frozen if it's unresponsive for several seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know it existed :P